# How to completely delete postgres?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I am new to postgres and I think I messed up my postgresql, so I want to delete postgresql so that I can reinstall it. The problem is that when I run the following command, the folder /etc/postgresql/9.5 still exists.

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

But this did not do the trick either.
Does anyone have an idea of how to delete postgresql completely?

Comment: [aside] this question has nothing to do with Python, for clarity you should remove that I think. Also it would probably help if you specified your distribution.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/187891/47132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were correct in the command to uninstall postgresql. The /etc/postgresql contains configuration files. You can remove that and other postgres directories yourself using

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/
sudo rm -rf /var/log/postgresql/
sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/
```

Base on [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/111161/222926), you may also have related packages installed you can list with

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

You can remove those using the same command

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove package-to-be-removed
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove postgresql using this command

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

Then list all the postgres related package

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

remove all the packages using the following command

```
apt-get --purge remove packagename1 packagename2 ..
```

Confirm all the files and folders related to postgres/postgresql are deleted and delete using `rm` command

```
whereis postgres
whereis postgresql
```

delete the postgres user using the command

```
userdel -f postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the packages related to PostgreSQL with just one line of code using a **wild card** `*`:

```bash
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql*
```

This means you remove all the packages which names start from "postgresql", `*` means "*and everything after*". While uninstalling you'll be additionally asked to remove the files associated with the postgres, in your case you should agree with that.

Then you can check whether some packages have left, with this command, for example (outputs the list of packages with the names that start with "postgr"):

```bash
sudo dpkg -l | grep postgr*
```

and it should give you no output (i.e. "no packages"). If you're not sure with the latest command, you can check it before removing anything - you will see the list of PostgreSQL packages.